# Complex regex with hexadecimal part

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex that matches the string:

```
HELLO[ID]_world.NNN
```

Where:

- 'HELLO' is constant. It must always start with this word
- 'ID' is any number
- 'world' is anything
- 'NNN' is the sequence number in hexadecimal notation, i.e. '000' to 'FFF'

For example valid strings are:

```
HELLO[345]_something.123
HELLO[23]_BlaBla.FFF
```

What I have so far is:

```
\bHELLO\[[0-9]*\]_[a-zA-Z]*\.[0-9]{3}
```

If I am correct (and maybe I am not) this works for all examples except hexadecimal part.

Could you help me to write this regex?

Comment: Have you tried `[0-9a-fA-F]{3}` instead?

Comment: You say *`'world' is anything`* but you use `[a-zA-Z]*` that only matches letters. Try [`\bHELLO\[[0-9]*]_\S*\.[a-fA-F0-9]{3}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/H77hjv/2/) If you need to only match *entire* strings, replace [`\b...\b` with `^...$`](https://regex101.com/r/H77hjv/3).

Comment: Also consider using `+` instead of `*` if you don't want to match `HELLO[]_.123`

Comment: [`\bHELLO\[[0-9]+\]_[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/nEkeBY/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match hexadecimal numbers, you just have to add `a-f` and/or `A-F` to the `[0-9]{3}` group, depending on whether you want to match upper- or lowercase hex numbers or both.

Also, as noted in comments, you might want to change the `*` to `+` to disallow empty strings for those parts.

```
HELLO\[[0-9]+\]_[a-zA-Z]+\.[0-9a-fA-F]{3}
```

[Online-Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xl3Ala/2)